# If the derivative of composition is 0, then is the derivative of each function 0?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h$ be a parametrized path such that $h(t) = u + t(v-u), t \in [0,1], u,v \in \mathbb R^2$. Let $g(t) = f(h(t))$, then $g'(t) = f'(h(t))h'(t)$. If $f'(h(t)) = 0$, then $g'(t) = 0$, but does that imply that $h'(t)=0$?

Comment: Since $h'(t)=v-u$, the only way that $h'(t) = 0$ if if $u=v$.

Comment: $h'(t)$ will not be $0$ anywhere unless $v-u= 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $u=(0,0), v=(1,0)$ so $ h(t)=(t,0)$. Let $f(x,y)=(0,y)$. Then $f(h(t))=0$ for all $t$ but $h'(t)\neq 0$.